# Does a TemplateRole have a RecipientId?

Tags: docusignapi

I am attempting to use the SignHere tabs in conjunction with TemplateRoles.

SignHere tabs take a RecipientId parameter. Does a TemplateRole have a RecipientId or is there a workaround to use SignHere tabs with TemplateRoles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template will define the recipient(s) as *role(s)*, including the role names, and their SignHere tab(s).

Then, when you want to use a template, you specify the role name when setting the recipients.

See an [example recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email-using-a-template).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have that working just fine, but then am able to specify additional recipients beyond what I have defined in the template. Template has 2 default recipients. I am adding a a dynamic number of recipients using TemplateRole and attempting to associate related SignHere tab(s) onto a custom generated Document. I am also using CompositeTemplate(with a server template and Document) for this structure. Please let me know if this structure sounds possible? Or should I be approaching this differently. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently when I add additional TemplateRoles and SignHere tab(s) beyond the defined template, the newly specified SignHere tabs are being required by every recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, sharing how I got it working.

I was able to accomplish this by using a different set of Tabs(containing SignHere tabs) for each TemplateRole.

My Structure is the following: 
So my template created in DocuSign has 2 default Roles.

Then when creating my envelope I was able to add a dynamic number of Roles beyond my default 2 on the template using TemplateRoles.

Each TemplateRole then has its own set of Tabs containing related SignHere Tabs for that specific TemplateRole.

This allows me to use a Template in conjunction with a custom generated document leveraging the CompositeTemplate envelope property.